# Where to put include php file?

Tags: php, forms, code

I have a third party php form code that starts with:

`<? include("xxx-xxx.php"); ?>
<form method="post" action="https://www.xxxxxx etc etc....`

Where do I have to put the xxx-xxx.php file for it to connect?

Comment: Your code example did not publish, please update your question. PHP include uses the relative path, similar to css.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I must say that I don't think this is a wordpress related question. That said I hope this following suggestion helps you go in the right direction…

Basically the `include("xxx-xxx.php");` already tells you where to put the `xxx-xxx.php` – in this case it should go into the same directory where the 'parent' is located.

If instead it looked like this: `include("incl/xxx-xxx.php");` then the `xxx-xxx.php`should instead go into the subdirectory "incl"

Answer (score 0):

If you put the include file into the same folder of the calling function, you should include it this way:

```
require_once( __DIR__ . '/xxx-xxx.php');
```

Comment: I am grateful you came back to me so quickly but my coding knowledge is VERY basic (to say the least). . .  I have put the: <? include("xxx-xxx.php"); ?>
<form method="post" action="https://www.xxxxxx etc etc.... in a WP 'page', and I understand that the .php file needs a 'path' but I don't understand which directory the page containing the code is in ? sorry guys I realise this is probably basic !!

Comment: you don't know where is the file to be included?